# Find parent of a href attribute and access specific property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tree view. Please check this [link](http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/) . It has an example for tree with link (just search for `Link enabled, or` on the page).

If you inspect the element with the name child 2, you will see something link this:

[image]

I should be able to search for `tag a with href set as #child2` and once I find that, I should find its parent (li tag) and then access `data-nodeis` property and return its value.

So far I am able to do this: $('a[href="#child2"]'); but not sure what do do next.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to traverse until you find the element you need:

```
var nodeValue = $('a[href="#child2"]').parents("li").attr("data-nodeid");
```

- [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) is good for when you are nested several elements deep.
- [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) is good if the element is a direct descendant

  - **this would work for your particular situation**
- [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) could work too, which traverses upwards, the difference is closest starts at the element and parents starts at the parent element

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/upd3vpdb/5/) for an example using `.parents()`
OR the snippet below:

```js
var nodeValue = $('a[href="#child1"]').parents("li").attr("data-nodeid");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = nodeValue;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-nodeid="1">
        <div><a href="#child1">child1</a></div>
        
    </li>
    <li data-nodeid="2">
        <div><a href="#child2">child2</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the ancestors (up the DOM node) [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)  or [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) can be used. Something like this should do it.

```
$('a[href="#child2"]').closest('li').data('nodeid');
```

OR

```
$('a[href="#child2"]').parents('li').data('nodeid');
```

Since the `li` is a direct parent you can also use just `.parent()`

`.closest()` or `.parent()` are pretty much the same just that `.closest()` 
matching starts from the current element itself.

```js
$(function() {

  var defaultData = [{
    text: 'Parent 1',
    href: '#parent1',
    tags: ['4'],
    nodes: [{
      text: 'Child 1',
      href: '#child1',
      tags: ['2'],
      nodes: [{
        text: 'Grandchild 1',
        href: '#grandchild1',
        tags: ['0']
      }, {
        text: 'Grandchild 2',
        href: '#grandchild2',
        tags: ['0']
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'Child 2',
      href: '#child2',
      tags: ['0']
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 2',
    href: '#parent2',
    tags: ['0']
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 3',
    href: '#parent3',
    tags: ['0']
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 4',
    href: '#parent4',
    tags: ['0']
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 5',
    href: '#parent5',
    tags: ['0']
  }];

  var alternateData = [{
    text: 'Parent 1',
    tags: ['2'],
    nodes: [{
      text: 'Child 1',
      tags: ['3'],
      nodes: [{
        text: 'Grandchild 1',
        tags: ['6']
      }, {
        text: 'Grandchild 2',
        tags: ['3']
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'Child 2',
      tags: ['3']
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 2',
    tags: ['7']
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 3',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-earphone',
    href: '#demo',
    tags: ['11']
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 4',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download',
    href: '/demo.html',
    tags: ['19'],
    selected: true
  }, {
    text: 'Parent 5',
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-certificate',
    color: 'pink',
    backColor: 'red',
    href: 'http://www.tesco.com',
    tags: ['available', '0']
  }];

  var json = '[' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Parent 1",' +
    '"nodes": [' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Child 1",' +
    '"nodes": [' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Grandchild 1"' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Grandchild 2"' +
    '}' +
    ']' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Child 2"' +
    '}' +
    ']' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Parent 2"' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Parent 3"' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Parent 4"' +
    '},' +
    '{' +
    '"text": "Parent 5"' +
    '}' +
    ']';


  $('#treeview1').treeview({
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview2').treeview({
    levels: 1,
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview3').treeview({
    levels: 99,
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview4').treeview({

    color: "#428bca",
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview5').treeview({
    color: "#428bca",
    expandIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
    collapseIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
    nodeIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark',
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview6').treeview({
    color: "#428bca",
    expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-stop",
    collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
    nodeIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    showTags: true,
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview7').treeview({
    color: "#428bca",
    showBorder: false,
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview8').treeview({
    expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-stop",
    collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
    nodeIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    color: "yellow",
    backColor: "purple",
    onhoverColor: "orange",
    borderColor: "red",
    showBorder: false,
    showTags: true,
    highlightSelected: true,
    selectedColor: "yellow",
    selectedBackColor: "darkorange",
    data: defaultData
  });

  $('#treeview9').treeview({
    expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-stop",
    collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
    nodeIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    color: "yellow",
    backColor: "purple",
    onhoverColor: "orange",
    borderColor: "red",
    showBorder: false,
    showTags: true,
    highlightSelected: true,
    selectedColor: "yellow",
    selectedBackColor: "darkorange",
    data: alternateData
  });

  $('#treeview10').treeview({
    color: "#428bca",
    enableLinks: true,
    data: defaultData
  });



  var $searchableTree = $('#treeview-searchable').treeview({
    data: defaultData,
  });

  var search = function(e) {
    var pattern = $('#input-search').val();
    var options = {
      ignoreCase: $('#chk-ignore-case').is(':checked'),
      exactMatch: $('#chk-exact-match').is(':checked'),
      revealResults: $('#chk-reveal-results').is(':checked')
    };
    var results = $searchableTree.treeview('search', [pattern, options]);

    var output = '<p>' + results.length + ' matches found</p>';
    $.each(results, function(index, result) {
      output += '<p>- ' + result.text + '</p>';
    });
    $('#search-output').html(output);
  }

  $('#btn-search').on('click', search);
  $('#input-search').on('keyup', search);

  $('#btn-clear-search').on('click', function(e) {
    $searchableTree.treeview('clearSearch');
    $('#input-search').val('');
    $('#search-output').html('');
  });


  var initSelectableTree = function() {
    return $('#treeview-selectable').treeview({
      data: defaultData,
      multiSelect: $('#chk-select-multi').is(':checked'),
      onNodeSelected: function(event, node) {
        $('#selectable-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was selected</p>');
      },
      onNodeUnselected: function(event, node) {
        $('#selectable-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was unselected</p>');
      }
    });
  };
  var $selectableTree = initSelectableTree();

  var findSelectableNodes = function() {
    return $selectableTree.treeview('search', [$('#input-select-node').val(), {
      ignoreCase: false,
      exactMatch: false
    }]);
  };
  var selectableNodes = findSelectableNodes();

  $('#chk-select-multi:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    console.log('multi-select change');
    $selectableTree = initSelectableTree();
    selectableNodes = findSelectableNodes();
  });

  // Select/unselect/toggle nodes
  $('#input-select-node').on('keyup', function(e) {
    selectableNodes = findSelectableNodes();
    $('.select-node').prop('disabled', !(selectableNodes.length >= 1));
  });

  $('#btn-select-node.select-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $selectableTree.treeview('selectNode', [selectableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-select-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-unselect-node.select-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $selectableTree.treeview('unselectNode', [selectableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-select-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-toggle-selected.select-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $selectableTree.treeview('toggleNodeSelected', [selectableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-select-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });



  var $expandibleTree = $('#treeview-expandible').treeview({
    data: defaultData,
    onNodeCollapsed: function(event, node) {
      $('#expandible-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was collapsed</p>');
    },
    onNodeExpanded: function(event, node) {
      $('#expandible-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was expanded</p>');
    }
  });

  var findExpandibleNodess = function() {
    return $expandibleTree.treeview('search', [$('#input-expand-node').val(), {
      ignoreCase: false,
      exactMatch: false
    }]);
  };
  var expandibleNodes = findExpandibleNodess();

  // Expand/collapse/toggle nodes
  $('#input-expand-node').on('keyup', function(e) {
    expandibleNodes = findExpandibleNodess();
    $('.expand-node').prop('disabled', !(expandibleNodes.length >= 1));
  });

  $('#btn-expand-node.expand-node').on('click', function(e) {
    var levels = $('#select-expand-node-levels').val();
    $expandibleTree.treeview('expandNode', [expandibleNodes, {
      levels: levels,
      silent: $('#chk-expand-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-collapse-node.expand-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $expandibleTree.treeview('collapseNode', [expandibleNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-expand-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-toggle-expanded.expand-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $expandibleTree.treeview('toggleNodeExpanded', [expandibleNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-expand-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  // Expand/collapse all
  $('#btn-expand-all').on('click', function(e) {
    var levels = $('#select-expand-all-levels').val();
    $expandibleTree.treeview('expandAll', {
      levels: levels,
      silent: $('#chk-expand-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });

  $('#btn-collapse-all').on('click', function(e) {
    $expandibleTree.treeview('collapseAll', {
      silent: $('#chk-expand-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });



  var $checkableTree = $('#treeview-checkable').treeview({
    data: defaultData,
    showIcon: false,
    showCheckbox: true,
    onNodeChecked: function(event, node) {
      $('#checkable-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was checked</p>');
    },
    onNodeUnchecked: function(event, node) {
      $('#checkable-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was unchecked</p>');
    }
  });

  var findCheckableNodess = function() {
    return $checkableTree.treeview('search', [$('#input-check-node').val(), {
      ignoreCase: false,
      exactMatch: false
    }]);
  };
  var checkableNodes = findCheckableNodess();

  // Check/uncheck/toggle nodes
  $('#input-check-node').on('keyup', function(e) {
    checkableNodes = findCheckableNodess();
    $('.check-node').prop('disabled', !(checkableNodes.length >= 1));
  });

  $('#btn-check-node.check-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkableTree.treeview('checkNode', [checkableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-check-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-uncheck-node.check-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkableTree.treeview('uncheckNode', [checkableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-check-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-toggle-checked.check-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkableTree.treeview('toggleNodeChecked', [checkableNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-check-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  // Check/uncheck all
  $('#btn-check-all').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkableTree.treeview('checkAll', {
      silent: $('#chk-check-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });

  $('#btn-uncheck-all').on('click', function(e) {
    $checkableTree.treeview('uncheckAll', {
      silent: $('#chk-check-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });



  var $disabledTree = $('#treeview-disabled').treeview({
    data: defaultData,
    onNodeDisabled: function(event, node) {
      $('#disabled-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was disabled</p>');
    },
    onNodeEnabled: function(event, node) {
      $('#disabled-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was enabled</p>');
    },
    onNodeCollapsed: function(event, node) {
      $('#disabled-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was collapsed</p>');
    },
    onNodeUnchecked: function(event, node) {
      $('#disabled-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was unchecked</p>');
    },
    onNodeUnselected: function(event, node) {
      $('#disabled-output').prepend('<p>' + node.text + ' was unselected</p>');
    }
  });

  var findDisabledNodes = function() {
    return $disabledTree.treeview('search', [$('#input-disable-node').val(), {
      ignoreCase: false,
      exactMatch: false
    }]);
  };
  var disabledNodes = findDisabledNodes();

  // Expand/collapse/toggle nodes
  $('#input-disable-node').on('keyup', function(e) {
    disabledNodes = findDisabledNodes();
    $('.disable-node').prop('disabled', !(disabledNodes.length >= 1));
  });

  $('#btn-disable-node.disable-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $disabledTree.treeview('disableNode', [disabledNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-disable-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-enable-node.disable-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $disabledTree.treeview('enableNode', [disabledNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-disable-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  $('#btn-toggle-disabled.disable-node').on('click', function(e) {
    $disabledTree.treeview('toggleNodeDisabled', [disabledNodes, {
      silent: $('#chk-disable-silent').is(':checked')
    }]);
  });

  // Expand/collapse all
  $('#btn-disable-all').on('click', function(e) {
    $disabledTree.treeview('disableAll', {
      silent: $('#chk-disable-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });

  $('#btn-enable-all').on('click', function(e) {
    $disabledTree.treeview('enableAll', {
      silent: $('#chk-disable-silent').is(':checked')
    });
  });



  var $tree = $('#treeview12').treeview({
    data: json
  });
  
  
  alert($('a[href="#child2"]').closest('li').data('nodeid'));
  
});
```

```html
<link href="http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/js/bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap Tree View</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Default</h2>
      <div id="treeview1" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Collapsed</h2>
      <div id="treeview2" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Expanded</h2>
      <div id="treeview3" class=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Blue Theme</h2>
      <div id="treeview4" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Custom Icons</h2>
      <div id="treeview5" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tags as Badges</h2>
      <div id="treeview6" class=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>No Border</h2>
      <div id="treeview7" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Colourful</h2>
      <div id="treeview8" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Node Overrides</h2>
      <div id="treeview9" class=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Link enabled, or</h2>
      <div id="treeview10" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Searchable Tree</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <!-- <form> -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-search" class="sr-only">Search Tree:</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input-search" placeholder="Type to search..." value="">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-ignore-case" value="false">Ignore Case
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-exact-match" value="false">Exact Match
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-reveal-results" value="false">Reveal Results
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-search">Search</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-clear-search">Clear</button>
      <!-- </form> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tree</h2>
      <div id="treeview-searchable" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <div id="search-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Selectable Tree</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-select-node" class="sr-only">Search Tree:</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input-select-node" placeholder="Identify node..." value="Parent 1">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-select-multi" value="false">Multi Select
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-select-silent" value="false">Silent (No events)
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success select-node" id="btn-select-node">Select Node</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger select-node" id="btn-unselect-node">Unselect Node</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary select-node" id="btn-toggle-selected">Toggle Node</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tree</h2>
      <div id="treeview-selectable" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Events</h2>
      <div id="selectable-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Expandible Tree</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-expand-node" class="sr-only">Search Tree:</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input-expand-node" placeholder="Identify node..." value="Parent 1">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-expand-silent" value="false">Silent (No events)
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success expand-node" id="btn-expand-node">Expand Node</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="select-expand-node-levels">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger expand-node" id="btn-collapse-node">Collapse Node</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary expand-node" id="btn-toggle-expanded">Toggle Node</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-expand-all">Expand All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="select-expand-all-levels">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-collapse-all">Collapse All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tree</h2>
      <div id="treeview-expandible" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Events</h2>
      <div id="expandible-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Checkable Tree</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-check-node" class="sr-only">Search Tree:</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input-check-node" placeholder="Identify node..." value="Parent 1">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-check-silent" value="false">Silent (No events)
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success check-node" id="btn-check-node">Check Node</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger check-node" id="btn-uncheck-node">Uncheck Node</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary check-node" id="btn-toggle-checked">Toggle Node</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-check-all">Check All</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-uncheck-all">Uncheck All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tree</h2>
      <div id="treeview-checkable" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Events</h2>
      <div id="checkable-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Disabled Tree</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-disable-node" class="sr-only">Search Tree:</label>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input-disable-node" placeholder="Identify node..." value="Parent 1">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk-disable-silent" value="false">Silent (No events)
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success disable-node" id="btn-disable-node">Disable Node</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger disable-node" id="btn-enable-node">Enable Node</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disable-node" id="btn-toggle-disabled">Toggle Node</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-disable-all">Disable All</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-enable-all">Enable All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Tree</h2>
      <div id="treeview-disabled" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>Events</h2>
      <div id="disabled-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
    <h2>Data</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2>JSON Data</h2>
      <div id="treeview12" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2></h2>
      <div id="treeview13" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2></h2>
      <div id="treeview14"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of `$("a[href='#child2']")` will work. It just needs some more code.

**1.** The `parent()` method returns the parent or direct ancestor. So using `$("a[href='#child2']").parent()` will return the `<li>` element.

**2.** Then you can access the attribute of the `<li>` tag using `attr()`. It takes the attribute name as it's first argument.

So altogether, you can do:

#### jQuery:

```
var i = $("a[href='#child2']").parent().attr("data-nodeid");
```

This way you can access the property. Variable `i` contains the `data-nodeid` attribute value.

**Notes:**
You can also use `parents("li")` instead of `parent()`.

Instead of `attr()` you can also use `data("nodeid")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate and add some context on how the OP can use this to solve the problem?